# PHP session_start doesn't resume session

Tags: php, session

I want to resume a session. So I'm passing session id and trying to resume session like so:

```
    session_save_path($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/mysessions');
    if(!empty($_POST['session_id'])) { 
      session_id($_POST['session_id']);  // $_POST['session_id'] = "4dkwkeiugraqhfpeq745l2c2a1";
      session_start();
    }

    $session_var = $_SESSION['property_name']; // <- null even though there was something there

    ob_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $session_data = ob_get_clean(); // $session_data = NULL
```

I see that physical session file exists '`sess_4dkwkeiugraqhfpeq745l2c2a1`' in the session folder where I store my sessions. Three is data there. However, the session does not resume. After calling `session_start()`, `$_SESSION` variables are not there.

What am I misssing here?

Comment: Have you tried with hardcoded session id? Have you checked the actual length of `$_POST['session_id']` (maybe there's whitespace inside)?

Comment: This happens after you close the page and enter again? Maybe the server is starting another session with a different id

Comment: I wouldn't use this. it allows for highly trivial session hijacking. unelss you have good reason to do so, don't mess with setting/changing session id's

Comment: `$_SESSION` being `NULL` means that the session didn't start (otherwise it would be (at least an empty) array). Check the return value of `session_start()` and verify it is true (and that the function is called). Not that you bark on the wrong tree here (e.g. never going inside the if). - You also should get a `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION` - enable your logging including warnings and check for errors. They often give you good hints when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

That's hard to say. `session_id()` is the correct function to change the session id, however the `session_save_path()` might be a different one. So you think the session is on the disk, but it's the wrong directory.

Or even a different save handler, so not even saving to disk but into database.

Also inside your code I don't see any check to test if the `$_SESSION` is actually empty or not, so it's not clear where you check that. You should test this directly after `session_start()` so that you know if the data was loaded or not.

Comment: I just looked and session_save_path returns a directory `/var/lib/php/session` which is not the path I'm saving my sessions in. I set the path explicitly before making the call. I'm not sure why it would get reset to something else. I'm assuming that `var/lib/php/session` is some kind of default?

Comment: `var/lib/php/session` is a default session path set in php.ini. Updated question to show code that sets path.